# Microsoft Excel - Global formula to arrange multiple pattern text as desired

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Source column and result I am looking for :

[image]

The purpose is to accelerate the process of rewrite street index from raw lists.

I think the formula must exhaustively list the different possible patterns (as shown above, the first part of the label is redundant, and the last part is unique).

The formula doesn't have to be infallible since I will always check by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,{"All De ","All Des ","Che Du ","Esp ","Imp De La ","R De La ","R De L'","R De ","R "},y,PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,x,,1))&" ("&{"Allée de","Allée des","Chemin du","Esplanade","Impasse de la","Rue de la","Rue de l'","Rue de","Rue"}&")",XLOOKUP(1,COUNTIF(A1,x&"*"),y,"No Match Found"))
```

Comment: Ok, your formula totally makes sense to me but since I use Excel 2019, I don't have the "XLOOKUP" formula...

Comment: PS : I just tried on Excel 365 : works like a charm ! Thank you.